# MongoDB query invalid

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using the database MongoDB and I trying to run a query that will check two things.

The query is timestamp is greater than time and server is not equals to name.

It would look like this in an if statement

```
if (timestamp > date && !server.equalsIgnoreCase("name")
```

This is the code I'm using to query

```
List<BasicDBObject> queryList = new ArrayList<>();
queryList.add(new BasicDBObject("timestamp",new BasicDBObject("$gt", lastCheck)));
queryList.add(new BasicDBObject("server",new BasicDBObject("$not","Dev")));
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$and",queryList);
```

I am getting this error when running the code

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure: command failed [count]: {                         "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "errmsg" : "exception: invalid use of $not" , "code" : 13041 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

I know I am using the $not operator wrong but hopefully someone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$ne` (for *not equal*) instead as shown [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/).

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer as well so others in the future know it worked for you. Good luck with your project!